# Difference between a Pure Abstract class and an Interface

Tags: c#, java, oop

I was having a discussion with a coworker, who insisted that in Languages such as Java and C# there is never any reason to use a Pure Abstract base class, as it simply means you are unable to get around the lack of multiple inheritance.

I feel that he is wrong about this, as I've always thought that if a thing is a noun then it is an object, and if it is a verb then it is an interface.

For example, if I wanted to define type `Bird`, where I wanted to enforce the method `fly` without implementing it, then I would make that a pure abstract class.

If I wanted to define a type `Flies`, I would make it an interface with the method `fly`.

`Bird` might implement `Flies`.

Am I wrong?

EDIT:

The only solid argument I can give to support my point of view is that at some point in the future the design might need to change so that birds can eat. If all birds eat the same then this would need to be added to `Bird`, making it non pure abstract.

If `Bird` had been an interface this change would simply be a nightmare, since I cannot know whether things that inherit from some other base class also implement my `Bird` interface, so I can't just refactor my problems away.

Comment: +1 - good question and i think there will be many rational reasons explored in the coming answers for the usecase of abstract classes.

Comment: Just picking up on *part* of your question (thus not posting an *answer*): I wouldn't say that interfaces are always *verbs* at all. Interfaces are used a *lot* to allow a class to show a face to world that is best modelled as a noun. Just look at some of the interfaces in `java.util`: `Comparator`, `Enumeration`, `List`, `Iterator`, `Map`, ...

Comment: Opinions are like backsides, everyones got one and some are better than others. I dont believe comparing OOP with Grammar is correct but its close.

Comment: to extend this analogy, I would say that interfaces are adjectives rather than verbs.  Interfaces describe the functionality that an object possesses, Abstract classes describe the hierarchy of a class.

Comment: What exactly is a _pure_ abstract class in C# ?

Comment: something like: abstract class A { public abstract string B(); }

Comment: why is this closed? really SO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from your first edit i.e some future requirement. One possible use-case could declaring a constant and initializing it in the abstract class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public abstract class AbstractPure implements ISomeInterface {
    public static final List<String> days = new ArrayList<String>();
    static{
        days.add("Monday");
        days.add("Tuesday");
        days.add("Wednesday");      
        days.add("Thursday");   
        days.add("Friday"); 
        days.add("Saturday");   
        days.add("Sunday"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically that's not a pure abstract class anymore...

Comment: Personally I think constants in interfaces are often a design issue - at least everything that can't be handled by primitives and enums. But it's a valid point that that's not possible with interfaces.

Comment: @zmbq: yes. technically a pure abstract would be same as the interface, which makes no sense in real world, well not to me. My answer is just talking in terms of an interface where you have constants and you want to initialize it. The above code snippet could be easily written as `class Days { List<String> days = new ArrayList(); ....}` and then use this class as a constant in any interface. Depends on the way a developer likes it.

Comment: @Voo: see my last comment. Even things other than primitives and enums could be handled in sensible ways :)

Comment: As it stands, `days` is mutable and perhaps not the best design decision for days in a week, which are constant.

Answer (score 10):

I can think of at least one good reason: You can extend abstract classes later on, without breaking backwards compatibility: Assume a class/interface

```
abstract class/interface Foo {
    void foo();
}
```

If we use an interface we now know for sure that there's no way to ever add additional functionality to Foo. This can lead to things like `interface Foo2 implements Foo`.

On the other hand if you have an abstract class you can easily add another method to it, as long as you provide a base implementation.

Note that Java8 will allow Interfaces to do basically the same thing - that'll be useful for library writers wanting to update their libraries to use lambdas without necessarily breaking compatibility to the millions of lines of code already written.

Comment: This is the only reason i can think of as well. To take the other side of the argument: How do you know when something will never need additional implemented functionality? When is something definitely an interface? Should i never use an interface for fear i might need to add some functionality to it down the line?

Comment: @sji In the end a judgment call that depends on the actual business case, so apart from the obvious I don't see much that can help us there in general. At least in Java there's also the fact that there's no multiple inheritance. With Java8 allowing interfaces to have default implementations of methods should go a long way to make this more clear-cut.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching on pure abstract classes (it's been a while since I last used C++), and the only use-case I could find for them was to define interfaces in C++ (which doesn't have interfaces).

So I would say if you can use a pure abstract class, you might as well go with an interface, like your friend said.

However, I've never come across the need for a pure abstract class in C#, so this is might be a hypothetical issue.

Comment: I do come from a c++ background, which may affect my thinking on this, again i have extended the question to illustrate a potential need for an abstract base class.

Comment: Yes, but how can you tell which interface is suddenly going to have to eat?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that both interfaces and classes define objects. As you yourself said it the verbs go to methods - they are properties of these objects. In your example of fly, I will declare an interface `FlyingCreature` and define a method fly in it (thus you have interfaces like `Comparable` and `Serializable` not `Serialize` and `Compare`. You have method `compareTo`). Also about your other example - bird: if you do not have any logic for the bird then you declare it as interface.

The interfaces are used to declare common properties different types of objects will have, they group them taxonomically. Afterwords, using the fact that you know they are of the same interface you will be able to process them the same way.

I don't see any gain in pure abstract class, as I already said both abstract classes and interfaces declare objects.

Comment: I have expanded my question to point out a potential drawback of making bird an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've got a plugin system going with multiple plugin types each of which implements a different interface.

Now, lets also say you're using reflection to find these plugin classes at runtime.

Since they are interfaces one plugin can be multiple types of plugin.

If you make each plugin type an abstract class then you control the inheritance hierarchy and can ensure each plugin is a distinct type.

So there is a difference between pure abstract classes and interfaces.  It's not one you'd need to use but neither is ++, recursion, or even objects.

Answer (score 0):

I read something not long ago related to this. It basically said that if the items are linked together then use an abstract class. If it describes properties of something then use an interface.

So using your example a bird would be an abstract class because you want an eagle or a parrot to derive from the same place.

If you just wanted something like "flyer" then you would make that an interface because birds and planes and other things might implement the interface but its only this one property that they have in common.

The other thing to consider is that at some point you might want to actually put some concrete methods for your bird. All birds fly in the same way after all so you might want the class to print "flap flap flap" whenever a bird flies. If you are using an interface you need to do that on each class (or then introduce a new base class) whereas if you've used an abstract class in the first place you just need to add the behaviour in one place.